# Owin selfhosted service does not release port

Tags: windows-services, owin

I have a Owin selfhosted Web.Api in a console application that I installed as a windows service.

Lets say the url for the service is http://localhost:12345. When I restart the windows service the service does not start back up because I get the following exception

> Application: xxx.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Net.HttpListenerException
>      at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
>      at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(System.Net.HttpListener, System.Func`2<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Object>, System.Func`2,Boolean>>)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(System.Func`2<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2)

This is the same exception you get when you are trying to run the Owin application on a port that is already in use.

So I then I used netstat when the service is running and indeed the port is taken, but when I stop the windows service the port is still used by the application. Eventually after a while the port is not showing up in netstat any more, then the application starts without a problem.

Is there any way to get this to happen automatically when the service restarts in stead of having to try until it succeeds.

Disclaimer : Not an expert on the network related stuffs....

Comment: Rookie mistake. I was not disposing the Owin WebApp, once I did this the problem went way.